# Calculate difference between multiple group columns in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

First post in stackoverflow - so forgive me if I don't get this right. I have an SSRS report with a matrix which groups Quantity, Total Spend and Average Cost by part number for each year. Part Number and description down the left and the the years along the top. I want to add a delta column in each year after the first year which shows the change in price from the previous year. I have seen examples of how to get the difference between first and last year - but not the difference between each year and the previous one. I have hidden the delta column for the first year - no would love some guidance on how to calculate the difference in cost.

So from the image below the first row in the delta column under FY2019 would show -€0.01 as price has reduced from 0.59 to 0.58.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't explained how if Avg. Cost is calculated in your report but I'm assumming it's just something like `=SUM(Fields!Spend.Value) / SUM(Fields!Qty.Value)`

You've not shown your report design so I can't tell what your row/column groups are called but I'll assume you have rowgroup by Part and one by Year. Let's assume your column group name is `PeriodID` so it's the same as my demo report.

In this case you can use the `PREVIOUS()` function to get the previous values to compare against.

[image]

I set up a similar report to demonstrate. As you can see in my case the year column is grouped using a columngroup called `PeriodID`

The expressions highlighted are as follows.

**Price**. This is just Cost/Qty `=SUM(Fields!Cost.Value)/SUM(Fields!Qty.Value)`

**lastprice**. This is just for illustration and debugging. It uses the `PREVIOUS()` fucntion to get the previous year's data

```
=Previous(Sum(Fields!Cost.Value), "PeriodID") / Previous(Sum(Fields!Qty.Value), "PeriodID")
```

Note that "PeriodID" is the name of the column group (case sensitive). This is scope for the previous function so it know to get data from the previous column group.

**delta**. This is the final output. It's just the current "Price" expression minus the "lastprice" expression.

```
=(Sum(Fields!Cost.Value) / Sum(Fields!Qty.Value)) - (Previous(Sum(Fields!Cost.Value), "PeriodID") / Previous(Sum(Fields!Qty.Value), "PeriodID"))
```

The final output looks like this (I've not hidden the column for the first column group or hidden last price, just so you can see it working). Also, if you see slight differences in the delta column compared to what you might expect, it's just down to the fact that the numbers are formatted to 2 decimals but my test data is up to 14 decimals.

[image]

Comment: Glad it worked. Can you please mark the answer as accepted (the check mark under the vote up/down buttons to the left). This helps others find answers to similar questions in the future.